# Edit file from boot iso Arch Linux

Tags: linux, boot, script, search

I've messed up a startup script on my Arch Linux machine and I cannot boot into KDE anymore to disable it.

Is there a way to delete (or move) that file from where it is so that the script will not run on startup? I've configured it to do so in the system settings GUI.

I feel like there has to be a way to access the files on my drives from the boot USB, but I'm having a blonde moment and can't remember how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Bash command line, something like this should do the trick:

```
mdkir /mnt/harddrive
mount -rw /dev/hda(whatever your hard drive partion name/number is) /mnt/harddrive
```

Then you can either cd into the drive at /mnt/harddrive or you can chroot into it to use it as the root directory while you fix the problem.

---

If you are unsure of the drive's partition numbers or name,

```
fdisk -l
```

should give you a full list of all storage devices currently connected to your computer, from which picking it out should be relatively easy.

Comment: I actually just realized that I could do something similar to this. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!